# Unable to Access Kubernetes LoadBalancer Service from Local Device Outside Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, metallb

I have set up a Kubernetes cluster with a single master node and three worker nodes running in VMs. Within this cluster, I deployed an nginx pod and created a LoadBalancer service using MetalLB to allocate an external IP address. The LoadBalancer service is exposing port 80, and when I SSH into the VM hosting the Kubernetes cluster and curl the external IP address, I receive the expected response from nginx.

However, when attempting to access the service from my local device using the same external IP address, I encounter a connection failure with the error message: "Failed to connect to  port 80 after 348 ms: Couldn't connect to server."

I suspect the issue may lie in the IP address range specified in the IPAddressPool of MetalLB. Currently, I've assigned an external IP address within the range of my master node. How can I determine the appropriate value for the IP address range in MetalLB's IPAddressPool to enable access to the LoadBalancer service from devices outside the Kubernetes cluster?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I created an nginx pod using below command

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=quay.io/redhattraining/hello-world-nginx
```

The result of `kubectl get deploy -oyaml` looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    creationTimestamp: "2024-03-30T08:34:01Z"
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app: nginx
    name: nginx
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "5748"
    uid: ff20a336-075e-45cd-9a2e-29110d3e9bce
  spec:
    progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
    replicas: 1
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: nginx
    strategy:
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
      type: RollingUpdate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: nginx
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: quay.io/redhattraining/hello-world-nginx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: hello-world-nginx
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        schedulerName: default-scheduler
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  status:
    availableReplicas: 1
    conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: "2024-03-30T08:34:20Z"
      lastUpdateTime: "2024-03-30T08:34:20Z"
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      status: "True"
      type: Available
    - lastTransitionTime: "2024-03-30T08:34:02Z"
      lastUpdateTime: "2024-03-30T08:34:20Z"
      message: ReplicaSet "nginx-774b9c499f" has successfully progressed.
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      status: "True"
      type: Progressing
    observedGeneration: 1
    readyReplicas: 1
    replicas: 1
    updatedReplicas: 1
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

**IPAddressPool**

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - <IP Range>
  autoAssign: true
  avoidBuggyIPs: false
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-lb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

`kubectl get svc` gives below result

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx-lb-service   LoadBalancer   <CLUSTER-IP>   <First IP in the pool>   80:30732/TCP   13h
```

when I take ssh into the vm which host k8s cluster and then run curl  I get the expected response

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world from nginx!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when I try the same from my local device it is giving me below response

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <IP> port 80 after 348 ms: Couldn't connect to server.
```

when nothing was not working I created L2Advertisement like

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: nginx-expose
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - first-pool
```

But that also didn't helped.

Note: I am not using minikube or kind cluster.

Comment: Is [strict ARP](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/#preparation) enabled, or not needed with your configuration?

Comment: ARP is not directly involved in the current issue and enabling it won't solve the external access problem

Answer (score 0):

**The  error is probably caused by the way MetalLB's IP Adress pool is configured.**

In your current configuration As of right now, MetalLB is configured to automatically assign an external IP address from the range that is provided in IPAdressPool.The service is accessible from within the cluster. The connection failed because the VM itself has a route for that IP range, but your local device does not have a route for the IP range that the MetalLB uses.

**To resolve your issue :**

- Verify whether the IP range listed in the IPAdresspool address is a publicly routable range.Private IP ranges cannot be used for external access.Update IPAdressPool with a public IP range supplied by your cloud provider or hosting environment if the present range is private.
- Verify again that the firewall rules on the virtual machines permit traffic on port 80.

**This solution should be working for your on-premises or cloud-based Kubernetes cluster since you aren't using Minikube or any similar product.**

Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/deploy/baremetal.md) for more information

**EDIT1**

**That's a positive step forward. You have verified that the external IP address that metalLB assigned to your network may be reached. The fact that curl fails and traceroute reaches the IP address yet ping succeeds shows that there may be a security restriction or an application layer port 80 problem.**

**Follow below Troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue**

Verify your [firewall settings](https://www.tigera.io/learn/guides/kubernetes-security/kubernetes-firewall/) on the VMS where Kubernetes is hosted .Make sure they permit inbound traffic for the particular interface that the Kubernetes pods utilize on port 80.To confirm this, you can use tools like **IPtables** or the firewall control console provided by your cloud provider.

In the K8s cluster, confirm that your [Nginx service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/connect-applications-service/) is set up to listen on port 80 and offer the proper application path. To inspect the service description and verify the port configuration, use **kubectl get svc nginx-lb-service -o yaml all**.

To rule out any issues with local settings on your Mac, try using curl to access the service from another device on your network, such as a separate PC or phone.

Check the NGINX container logs within the k8s cluster if the preceding methods are ineffective in identifying the issue. To find out whether NGINX has reported any faults or access issues, you can use the **kubectl logs deployment/NGINX** command.

Remember that there are security concerns associated with exposing your service to the internet. Make that the Internet access control settings for your NGINX container are set correctly. It is not advised to expose sensitive data without appropriate authentication.

To find out if requests are reaching the NGINX container, try capturing network traffic on port 80 using a tool like **tcpdump** on the VM hosting the K8S service.

When utilizing a cloud provider, go to their official doc for detailed instructions on how to configure metalLB and external load balancing.